# Replace an HTML tag in an HTML document using Python without modifying the rest of the document

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I'm making a simple Python + HTML website (as part of my study). The website menu looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

This block is stored in a variable, and when any page is generated, other content is concatenated to the variable, and a generated page is transferred to a client (a browser).

I'm trying to get a currently opened menu item to become bold (add B tag) and remove the link (get rid of A tag). For example if Products page is opened, the menu should be changed to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><b>Products</b></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) and [BeautifulSoup](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup), but I don't understand how to change only some parts of HTML, not ruining the whole HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use BeautifulSoup. Let's make a Python function.

```
def get_menu_html(current_page_name):
    # each <li> tag has its own ID
    html = """
        <ul>
            <li id="menu_home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu_products"><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li id="menu_about"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # find the tag <li> by ID
    tag = soup.find(id="menu_" + current_page_name)

    # create a new tag <b> with the same text as in <li>
    newtag = soup.new_tag("b")
    newtag.string = tag.get_text()

    # replace <a> inside <li> to <b>
    # so <li><a>...</a></li> turns into <li><b>...</b></li>
    tag.find("a").replace_with(newtag)

    # return prettified HTML
    return soup.prettify()
    
# try it
print(get_menu_html("products"))
```

You will get:

```
<ul>
 <li id="menu_home">
  <a href="/">
   Home
  </a>
 </li>
 <li id="menu_products">
  <b>
   Products
  </b>
 </li>
 <li id="menu_about">
  <a href="/about.html">
   About
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```